# How to send JavaScript based in a element in capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am looking to do something like this in Capybara:

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'value')", element)
```

The above  line is run on selenium/ruby, but using execute_script with capybara takes only 1 parameter (the script), hence I am unable to define the element I wish to execute the script on... any ideas?

Comment: Where does `element` come from?

Comment: element = browser.find_element(:id, 'idoflement')

Comment: what about `browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('idofelement').setAttribute('value', 'value')")`?

Comment: Yep, it did the trick... so did the solution below using selenium and bypassing capybara... not sure which is the best convention tho... Now I have a easier problem to solve(choose which approach to use), thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1 - Call Selenium's execute_script directly**

The quickest solution would be to bypass the Capybara API and call Selenium-WebDriver's `execute_script` method directly.

To do this, you will need to access the underlying Selenium::WebDriver::Driver using:

```
page.driver.browser
```

As well, the elements that get passed to Selenium's `execute_script` will need to be Selenium::WebDriver::Element (rather than the Capybara::Node::Element). This is done by:

```
element.native
```

As an example, say you have a page with the text field:

```
<input value="5" id="field">
```

Then the following will change the field's value:

```
element = find('#field')
p element.value
#=> "5"
page.driver.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'value')", element.native)
p element.value
#=> "value"
```

**Option 2 - Patch Capybara to allow arguments**

If you need to do this frequently, you could monkey-patch Capybara's `execute_script` method to take arguments, convert the arguments to Selenium objects and then pass it to Selenium-WebDriver's method. The patch would be:

```
require 'capybara'

class Capybara::Session 
  def execute_script(script, *args)
    @touched = true
    driver.execute_script(script, *args)
  end
end

class Capybara::Selenium::Driver 
  def execute_script(script, *args)
    args.map! { |e| e.kind_of?(Capybara::Node::Element) ? e.native : e }
    browser.execute_script(script, *args)
  end
end
```

This would then allow you to pass Capybara elements to the session `execute_script` method:

```
element = page.find('#field')
p element.value
#=> "5"
page.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'value')", element)
p element.value
#=> "value"
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Capybara 2.12 parameter passing via Session#execute_script is supported, and should work with the latest poltergeist and capybara-webkit drivers too.

```
page.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'value')", element)
```